# vibration in / vibration from

Tags: prepositions

I am translating a novel, and I am confused about which preposition is the better choice.  This is the scene: *A woman suddenly feels a vibration, which is from her cellphone in her purse.* Should I write

> She feels a vibration ***in*** her purse

or

> She feels a vibration ***from*** her purse

?

Comment: It could be either one.  Which one "feels" better to you??

Answer (score 1):

As it's describing where the vibrating is coming from, I'd go with "..vibration from her purse."  (or, alternately, "She feels her purse vibrating")